How does dialectical causality work in practice?
I'm currently reading Evan Thompson's Mind in Life (2007). He was a collaborator of Fransisco Varela on Autopoiesis so he expands it from biological forms to, ultimately, cognitive science. It's an interesting read so far.
Anyways, I'm not so far into the book but Thompson talks about the idea of dialectical causality (or as he oftentimes calls it, co-dependent causality, probably to distinguish from Hegelian notions). He follows Marleau-Ponty (and a few others) in differentiating between "mechanical causality", or linear causality - in which A is the cause of B, and B cannot be the cause of A, and "dialectical causality", or dynamic/co-dependent causality - in which both A is the cause of B, and B is the cause of A, such that they both affect each other.
Thompson notes that in doing so, Marleau-Ponty precedes contemporary complex systems theory. Now, I'll admit I'm not familiar with complex systems theory, but I can't really comprehend how such dynamic causality can work in practical scientific work - if A and B are both causes to each other, it means you cannot separate them and study each individually. For me this echoes exactly Fodor's "first law of the non-existence of the cognitive sciences" - if cognition (or perhaps more specifically, metacognition) cannot be modular (i.e. split to sub-systems), then we cannot study cognition.
Because Thompson seems like a reasonable philosopher, I imagine his ideas have at least some basic grounds and shouldn't be dismissed easily. So I do want to understand (because it doesn't seem like he'll get to it later in the book) - how exactly can one investigate a system where the internalized causes cannot be separated?

"Reciprocal (or bidirectional) causation" is a more commonly used term, and refers to mutual influences as in feedback systems. Drack and Wolkenhauer survey how Weiss and Bertalanffy proposed to study biological systems with such effects in the early systems theory:"The whole organism may be investigated to arrive at principles that are valid for the whole, whereby the physico-chemical determination in the detail is left aside... Bertalanffy advocates the search for laws of higher order."

It's really simple. An egg causes a chicken. And chicken causes eggs. That's it. There is nothing mysterious behind this. But now you have to consider evolutionary processes. Really not all eggs are the same -- some may be infertile, some may lead to mutated chicken... who may lead bigger eggs... etc. (The word "dialectic" seems a pretentious way to puff up one's "holistic" view of this. The word "co-dependent" seems misleading.) There are no problems separating chickens and eggs. Whether one is seen as a cause or an effect depends on what one wants to know.

You might find it interesting to read David Haig's essays in From Darwin to Derrida (https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262043786/from-darwin-to-derrida/) -- with introduction by Daniel Dennett. He gives an indepth and (just as important) down-to-earth analysis of this (based on his knowledge both of the history of philosophy and science and on his own work in evolutionary biology).


As far as I understand your paraphrase from Evan Thompson's book
he speaks about:

Linear chains of causality
and circular chains of causality.

It is well-known that “circular chain of causality” is an important
and indispensible concept for understanding life in general (cf.
‘hypercycle’ according to Eigen) and mental processes in particular
(cf. ‘reentrant information processing’ according to Edelmann-Tononi).

But to me it seems necessary to strip the whole text from its
philosophical name-dropping like Hegel, dialectical, Merlau-Ponty,
dynamic/co-dependent. I also question how a “law of the
non-existence of the cognitive sciences” can be in existence against
current neuroscience.

Concerning Eigen’s hypercycle I refer to hypercycle,
and concerning
Edelmann-Tononi to neural circuitry. Both show circular chains of causality in practice.



Thanks, I'll look into your references. I would add though, it seems weird that you'd want to strip a philosophical work from it's philosophy. Hegel, specifically, was my addition (to exactly differentiate Hegelian dialectics from the dialectical causality Thompson argues for). By the way, Fodor's law is philosophically (and scientifically) valid even now, to my knowledge. It hasn't been proven otherwise, some cogsci simply hope that it's invalid. Which is fine ofc.
